# How to Trim permissionset in XML automatically

Tags: force.com, eclipse, ide, permission-sets

How can I download only those permission that are set to 'true'? 
When I create permissionset and download it through FORCE.COM IDE (eclipse) I received thousands unnecessary permissions.
It is difficult to manage the file. 

Does anyone know how could I trim or remove permission that are set to false? 

I think doing it manually is not proper way.

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <name>CanUseNewDashboardBuilder</name> 
</userPermissions> 
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <name>ChatterComposeUiCodesnippet</name> 
</userPermissions> 
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>false</enabled>
    <name>ChatterEditOwnPost</name> 
</userPermissions>
```

Comment: you can write small tool (e.g. in Java) that manipulate the xml, not sure it worth it. Usually I create permissionSet once, refresh to with eclipse and delete manually all except true permission. It usually not going to be changed too often.

Answer (score 0):

you can open the large file in a text-editor that supports "regex" searching.  Here is a screen recording of the proper regex needed to find all occurrences of the nodes that you care about. If you're using Sublime Text 3 you can perform the regex search, and click "find all" to select all of the matches.  Then Copy it to your clipboard and paste it into a new file to get rid of the stuff you don't care about.  See it done here https://gust.box.com/s/kr6ynb2e016xfjffzsl55w5sl1g15vqa and let me know if you have any questions. Good luck!

here too 
`<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true[\s\S]*?</userPermissions>`